# Record owner is Inactive in Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a logic whenever Task is created/updated if the task owner is Active. for that I have just written sample class to test it. I am getting the owner is always inactive, even though running is user is active in the system. Why the owner is coming as Inactive?

**Sample Class:**

```
public class TaskSampleTrigger {
    public static void createTrialOpportunity(Task record){
       Task rec=[SELECT id,owner.isActive FROM Task where id=:record.Id LIMIT 1];
    Boolean validTouch=isValidTouch( record);
    System.debug('******Recor****** '+rec);
    System.debug('******Queried User is Active****** '+rec.owner.isActive);
    System.debug('******User is Active****** '+validTouch);
    }
    
    public static Boolean isValidOwner(Task record){
        return record.owner.isActive;
                                                          
   }
                                                      
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
private class TaskSampleTriggerTest {
    static testMethod void createSampleTest(){
        
        Lead newLead = TestingUtils.createLeads(1, 'Sample')[0];
        newLead.Email = 'sample@msample.com';
        newLead.Country='United States';
        insert newLead;     
        
        
        Account account = TestingUtils.createAccounts(1, new String[]{'TEST'})[0]; 
        account.BillingCountry ='United States';
        insert account;
        
        Task[] tasks = new Task[0];
        tasks.add(new Task(WhoId = newLead.Id, Lead__c=newLead.Id, Priority='High',Status='Completed',Status_Detail__c ='1',Subject='AATest',Type='Call'));
        
        
        insert tasks;         
        
    }
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Relationships are not automatically populated in trigger context, so, presumably, you're trying to do something like:

```
for(Task record: Trigger.new) {
  TaskSampleTrigger.createTrialOpportunity(record);
}
```

`Owner` is not populated, so `Owner.IsActive` returns false (the default value for this field).

Comment: yes, I get it, but I am trying to explicitly querying the record owner, but why is it still returning false? queried field is also returning false. am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Test classes are not run in the context of user executing them ...

Use System.runAs method to mimic a user and make sure for to define isActive true for this user and insert records with this user as owner

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm

Comment: Running tests as a particular user could be helpful in some contexts. However, this is not the issue in this particular case (the issue appears to be attempting to access related data from a record from a trigger context variable).